# Interpolation of a data set

Tags: r, dataset, interpolation

I am developing an linux kernel module in which I want to evaluate the level of battery power supply. I measured the voltage on the battery during charging. As a result, I received [the experimental dependence](https://gist.github.com/4193923) such as:

```
10:28:15    7898
10:29:15    7902
10:30:15    7908
10:31:15    7913
10:32:15    7918
10:33:15    7921
```

[image]

Now I need to interpolate the resulting graph with second-degree polynomial.

How can I do this with R programming language?

Comment: Second-degree polynomials between points, or one across the whole graph?

Comment: One across the whole graph.

Comment: The graph is clearly non-quadratic. But if you insist, read `?lm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lm` to fit a linear model to data:

```
> x <- 0:9
> y <- 1+2*x+3*x^2
> fit <- lm( y ~ x + I(x^2) )
> fit

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + I(x^2))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x       I(x^2)  
          1            2            3
```

But you should probably reconsider your quadratic model of this data.